# Kinetic energy in 3d rotational movement

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, rotation

[image]

When we calculate the angular momentum in this example we have 3 components (1 orbital and 2 spin components). Does the same hold for its Kinetic Energy? Like this:
$$
K=\frac12\left(I_s \Omega^2 + I_\text{cm1} \omega^2 +I_\text{cm2} \Omega^2 \right)
$$
Or is it just the first 2 terms?

Edit: Now that I think about it, maybe the third term is "included" in the 1st due to the parallel axis theorem for moment of inertia?

Comment: How are you defining $I_s$ and $I_\text{cm}$?

Comment: @MichaelSeifert If I remember correctly the moment of Inertia for a ring rotating around its centre of mass and normal to the plane of the ring is: $I=MR^2$ and around its diameter is: $I=(MR^2)/2$ so $I_{cm}=MR^2$ and using the parallel axis theorem $I_s=(MR^2)/2+Mb^2$.

Comment: It's not clear to me why there are necessarily two spin angular momenta here. Perhaps also related to what @MichaelSeifert asked, note that you can write the term involving $\Omega$ as $((I_{s}+I_\text{cm}) \Omega^2)/2$ which suggests you can define the moment of inertia differently and hence there will be one term for spin and another for orbital angular momentum?

Comment: @Amit because the wheel spins around its diameter about the z-axis, if we don't include that spin in the spin angular momentum it's like saying that the wheel is oriented in the z-θ plane throughout the rotation but since it is attached to a lever that is simply impossible. At least that's what I understood from lectures/course book. Maybe you can understand it better that my explanation here [link](https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Classical_Mechanics/Classical_Mechanics_(Dourmashkin)/22%3A_Three_Dimensional_Rotations_and_Gyroscopes/22.01%3A_Introduction_to_Three_Dimensional_Rotations).

Comment: @MichaelSeifert I jus realized a mistake I had there are 2 $I_{cm}$ , $I_{cm1}=MR^2$ and $I_{cm2}= (MR^2)/2$.

Comment: @PaNP - what I am confused about is you saying that there are two spin components. Perhaps you mean that the spin angular momentum has an orbital and a "pure" spin contribution, but it is still a single spin angular momentum as far as I can understand

Comment: @Amit maybe I'm not explaining it well, check the link in my previous comment, I think it's more clear in that site/book

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\def \b {\mathbf}$

[image]

The Kinetic energy is:

$$T=\frac 12 M\,\b v_w\cdot\b v_w+I_r\,\b\omega_w\cdot\b\omega_w\tag 1$$

the wheel  CM is rotating about the z-axis with the angle $~\Omega\,t~$, thus the position vector to the CM

$$\b R_{\rm CM}=\b S_z(\Omega\,t)\,\begin{bmatrix}
  0 \\
  b \\
  0 \\
\end{bmatrix}\\
\b v_{w}=\frac{d}{dt}\b R_{\rm CM}$$

The wheel   rotation matrix is:

$$\b S_w=\b S_z(\Omega\,t)\,\b S_y(\omega\,t)$$

From here you obtain the angular velocity $~\b\omega_w~$

$$\b\omega_w=\begin{bmatrix}
  -\sin(\Omega\,t)\,\omega \\
  \cos(\Omega\,t)\omega \\
\Omega \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

$~\Rightarrow~$ Substituting into equation $(1)$:

$$T=\frac 12\left(M\,b^2\,\Omega^2+I_r\,(\omega^2\,+\Omega^2)\right)$$

Comment: Are you picking out only the $y$ component of $\omega_{w}$ when you're substituting at the end? Otherwise the full dot product seems to lead to a different result...

Comment: @Amit I will check It, but to obtain the result I use symbolic program.

Comment: Sorry, but the last expression of T seems to depend (periodically) on time, but there is no external work done.

Comment: @Eli - It seems to me that $\omega_w \cdot \omega_w = \sin^2(\Omega t)\omega^2 +  \cos^2(\Omega t)\omega^2 + \Omega^2 = \omega^2 + \Omega^2$ so the last term in the energy should be $I_r(\omega^2 + \Omega^2)$ If I'm not wrong.

Comment: No this is correct ! Thanks

Comment: @Cisfinite see new edit